# Need help with identify device and its possible functions

Tags: pcb, identification

My boss found some device at his office. My task is to find out what the device is, what is its function and everything i can find about it. It may be some kind of test that expose that I can handle problems or give up with nothing. I'm not an electronic type of man :( Device is broken so i can't guess just by using it.

I guess it can be a part of playing postcard or some box that activate sound when opened but need to be 100% sure if my guess are right.

Searching in Internet using search by picture i found on electronics.stackexchange device looks 100% the same as mine. Link below

[What is the black thing on the circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/158230/what-is-the-black-thing-on-the-circuit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Need help and best option is just ask user about his device(author of question i found) but how?

Here is pic of my device
[image]

Comment: *I guess it can be a part of playing postcard or some box that activate sound when opened but need to be 100% sure if my guess are right.* - what will happen if you are not 100% sure? Your guess seem legit.

Comment: Ah, missed the boss part. That's a weird task. Is your boss some paranoid who thinks it's a listening device or something?

Comment: He just simply put it on my desk and ask to find anything about it. I have hered that he likes that kind of stupid games and if ppl handle the problem they got rewards (some days off, some bonuses, parking space or some things like that). If they can't handle the task or just do nothing they on "black list" to do things that no one want to do and someone just need to be pointed to do. (sorry my englisch)

Comment: Lol. That's weird. May I ask what your "official" duty is? :)

Comment: Tell him it is 5G chip used to spread COVID-19 :P anyway, your guess is correct. I even have kind of proof for you: https://xinditai.en.alibaba.com/product/60841955389-807025119/High_quality_postcard_music_module_mp3_sound_chip.html

Comment: If he knows what this is I will definetly be fired after that kind of answer :D

Got time till monday. I hope someone know what this is :)

Comment: You might have missed the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Hard to tell what it does without it working.  But there are trick devices which contain a photosensor.  When you turn the light off, they make an annoying chirruping noise.  If you turn the light on to find what's making the noise, they stop.  These are intended to be hidden in somebody's bedroom.

Comment: @EugeneSh. why not post your find as an answer? BTW I can't verify it because alibaba.com is blocked in my browser.

Comment: ask your boss to stop wasting your work productivity with silly tests

Comment: I think my first guess was right.

Thank you all.